# Using mprotect() to set main() as writeable

Tags: c, shellcode

Using [mprotect](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html) to set `main()` as writeable correctly works using this code.

https://godbolt.org/z/68vfrTq8z

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main()
{
    long page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
    printf("page_size    = %li\n", page_size);

    void* main_address = (void*)&main;
    printf("main_address = %p\n",main_address);
    
    void* main_start = (void*)(((uintptr_t)&main) & ~(sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE) - 1));
    printf("main_start   = %p\n", main_start);

    size_t main_size = (void*)&&main_end - (void*)&main;
    printf("main_size    = %d\n", main_size);

    mprotect(main_start, main_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC);

    // nop the breakpoint to allow printf() to run!
    *((char*)&&breakpoint) = 0x90;

breakpoint:
    __asm("int $3");

    printf("\nHello, World!\n");

    return 0;
    
main_end:
}
```

The program outputs

```
page_size    = 4096
main_address = 0x401156
main_start   = 0x401000
main_size    = 193

Hello, World!
```

**Question**

I initially coded it passing `main_address` to [mprotect](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html) but it failed with an "Invalid argument" (22) error because it was not aligned to a page boundary! Passing `main_start` works because it's the aligned address of the program entry point, but what is `main_address` and
why isn't it initially aligned too?

What's confusing me is that if `mprotect(0x401000, 193, ...)` is being write enabled, but the `main_address` is at 0x401156 which is `342` bytes further down in memory, how is the `main()` still writeable? Does `mprotect()` modify pages and not a specific byte range?

If pages are being write enabled, does that potentially imply memory portions past the end of `main()` are also writeable?

Comment: What do you mean “what is `main_address`”? It is your variable in your code, so it is what you set it to be and what you meant it to be. Did you expect it to be aligned? Why? Who told you that `main` would be aligned to a page boundary? Why would it be?

Comment: Note that making the page containing `main` writeable is not always sufficient to make changing the code work. Instructions may be cached separately from data, so a change made via a store instruction might not affect program execution until other steps are taken to deal with the cache.

Comment: Memory protection works in units of pages. The `len` argument is used only to know how many pages are to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [POSIX documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mprotect.html):

> The  *mprotect*()  function shall change the access protections to be that specified by *prot*
> for those whole pages containing any part of the address space of the process starting  at
> address  *addr*  and  continuing  for *len* bytes.

So by that, it will figure out which pages contain the specified bytes (effectively, rounding *addr* down to a page boundary and *addr+len* up to a page boundary) and change the permissions on those pages.  So it may affect the permissions on bytes before and after the range requested.

However, under errors it says:

> The *mprotect*() function may fail if:
>
> **EINVAL** The *addr* argument is not a multiple of the page size as returned by *sysconf*().

So a non-page aligned *addr* may fail instead of rounding down, but a non-page aligned *len* will work.  In practice, it depends on the actual OS -- some POSIX systems support unaligned addresses here and others do not.

Comment: I assume the 342 bytes before `main()` is maybe C runtime initialization that calls `main()`, so `mprotect` is making this page range `0x401000 - 0x402000` writeable, thus it's actually write enabling 3561 (4096-342-193) bytes past the of `main()`, right? Probably should load gdb to confirm. Thanks!

Comment: The space before main will have whatever you've linked before main.  That will generally include any functions defined in your .c file before main, as well as the C runtime startup code.  If main happens to start towards the end of a page and goes into the next page, just rounding down `&main` will fail to get all of it -- you also need to round up len.

Comment: Based on your answer, I can change the example to pass the `main_size` = 1 (instead of calculating the size of main) which will write enable 4096 bytes and so as long as `main()` is fully contained within that page, all is good. :)